# tensorflow how to do case when logic

Tags: tensorflow

I need to bucketize values of a tensor as below, but I cannot find an good approach to do it. A most close to success try was use `np.select`, however encountered `This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported` error in production.

```
case
when 0<a<11: then 1
when 11<=a<24: then 2
when 24<=a<30: then 3
...
when 95<=a<100: then 9
else 0 
end
```

Comment: When using Tensors in Tensorflow, you should use Tensorflow functions. In your case did your try using the tensorflow version of select? Also you can check the tf.where function.